# Nextjs error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, next.js, null

I keep getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null

whenever I try pulling data from the firestore database. The error points to when I am using the useState and this is how my code looks like

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebaseconfig'
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const reference = collection(db, "students");
const [students, setstudents] = useState([]);

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(reference);
    setstudents(data.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));

    return {
        props: students
    }
}
function Card({students}) {
  return (
    <div>
        {students.map(student => (
            <h1>{student.name}</h1>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: Hooks need to be used inside react function components. Try moving your useState inside Card component

Comment: I have tried that but then another issue arises which is I'd have to move the getStaticProps inside of the Card function so as to access the setstudents and when I do move it it says i cannot use the export method inside of the card function

Answer (score 1):

In the code snippet you have provided, the state `students` does not have any other purpose than being sent as props to Card component.

Based on the nextjs docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#using-getstaticprops-to-fetch-data-from-a-cms) , modify the code like this and try

```
import React from 'react'
import { db } from '../firebaseconfig'
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const reference = collection(db, "students");

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(reference);
    const students=data.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}));

    return {
        props: {
           students
        }
    }
}
function Card({students=[]}) {
  return (
    <div>
        {students.map(student => (
            <h1>{student.name}</h1>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Comment: this is a strange problem the error still persists it still says cannot read property of map. I'm starting to think this is beyond nextjs and something else is affecting it because your example is exactly like in the documentation but it is still refusing

Comment: Probably students is undefined. Check the data coming in `data.docs` using console.log(). also check my recent edit, assigned a default value for props.

Comment: it has solved the error but now it is returning an empty page so yeah the data.docs is probably empty so that means it is a firestore issue? Another strange thing is I am getting nothing from the console.log just emptyness

Answer (score 1):

From React Docs there are rules to using Hooks.
[React Hooks Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdTav.png)

Your code should look like this:

```
function Card({students}) {
    const [students, setstudents] = useState([]);
      return (
        <div>
            {students.map(student => (
                <h1>{student.name}</h1>
            ))}
        </div>
      )
}
```

This should solve your bug.

Answer (score 0):

Change  `setstudents` to `setStudents` and I suggest simplify your code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { db } from '../firebaseconfig'
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

function Card() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const fetchStudents=async()=>{
    const response=db.collection('students');
    const data=await response.get();
    setStudents(data.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
    );
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudents();
  }, [])

return (
  <div>
    {students && students.map(student => (
        <h1>{student.name}</h1>
    ))}
  </div>
  )
}
export default Card
```

Answer (score -3):

you are using 2 react imports. Make it one

try this:

import React, { useState}  from 'react'

Comment: Multiple imports from same library are not an issue. Using `useState` outside of a component is.